# Selecting value from array with a range?

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array on php that will return a lot of keys->values, like this:

```
Array 
 [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [value] => 405 
        [information] => some information1
    ) 
 [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [value] => 500
        [information] => some information2
    ) 
 [2] => Array 
    ( 
        [value] => 700
        [information] => some information3
    )
```

the values are numbers, i need to collect all the values, check the first one that will be >= $determinedvalue and then return the value "information" for this exactly array, is this even possible? I know i can do this if i create a temp table on my database, but i dont want to.

To be more clearly, when my value is "430" it will return me "some information2".

I've searched a lot on google but by now i dont know if this is even possible.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample on how to do that.  Comments in code can be used to explain the execution.

```
// Sample Array
$arr = array( 
 array
    ( 
        "value" => 405,
        "information" => "some information1"
    ),
 array
    ( 
        "value" => 500,
        "information" => "some information2"
    ),
 array
    ( 
        "value" => 700,
        "information" => "some information3"
    ) 
);

// Sample Number
$numberToCheck = 430;

// Sub Array To Assign
$subArray = array();

// Loop Through Outer Array
for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++)
{

    // If Value In Array > Number Check
    if ( $arr[$i]['value'] >= $numberToCheck )
    {
        $subArray = $arr[$i]; // Assign Sub Array
        $i = sizeof($arr); // This is Used to Exit For Loop
    }


}
print_r($subArray); // Print
```

Answer (score 0):

Working runnable code: https://tech.io/snippet/QJ93AwV

Code snippent with comments:

```
<?php

/**
 * Helper class for stable sort alogithms
 * @see https://github.com/vanderlee/PHP-stable-sort-functions
 * Class StableSort
 */
class StableSort
{
    static public function usort(array &$array, $value_compare_func)
    {
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($array as &$item) {
            $item = array($index++, $item);
        }

        $result = usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($value_compare_func) {
            $result = call_user_func($value_compare_func, $a[1], $b[1]);
            return $result == 0 ? $a[0] - $b[0] : $result;
        });

        foreach ($array as &$item) {
            $item = $item[1];
        }

        return $result;
    }

}

$array = [
    // added for test sorting
    [
        'value' => 9999,
        'information' => 'some information-1',
    ],
    [
        'value' => 1200,
        'information' => 'some information0',
    ],
    // \added for test sorting
    [
        'value' => 405,
        'information' => 'some information1',
    ],
    // added for test sorting stability
    [
        'value' => 405,
        'information' => 'some information1.2',
    ],
    [
        'value' => 405,
        'information' => 'some information1.1',
    ],
    // \added for test sorting stability
    [
        'value' => 500,
        'information' => 'some information2',
    ],
    [
        'value' => 700,
        'information' => 'some information3',
    ],
];

// sort array
$determinedvalue = 430;
StableSort::usort($array, function ($item1, $item2) {
    if ($item1['value'] == $item2['value']) return 0;
    return $item1['value'] < $item2['value'] ? -1 : 1;
});

// then select the first element by condition
$res = null;
foreach($array as $v) {
    if($v['value'] >= $determinedvalue) {
        $res = $v['information'];
        break;
    }
}

// for testing
print $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $number = 430;

    $array = Array 
     [0] => Array 
        ( 
            [value] => 405 
            [information] => some information1
        ) 
     [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [value] => 500
            [information] => some information2
        ) 
     [2] => Array 
        ( 
            [value] => 700
            [information] => some information3

         ) 

    $firstArray = $array[0];
    $secondArray = $array[1];
    $threeArray = $array[2];



function selectValueFromArrayRange ($number, $start, $end, $value, $infomation) 
{
    $startValue = $start[$value];
    $endValue = $end[$value];

    if ( in_array($number, range($startValue, $endValue)) ) {
        return $end[$infomation];
    }
}


selectValueFromArrayRange($number, $firstArray, $secondValue, 'value', 'infomation')
```